# Celery EncodeError(TypeError('Object of type Response is not JSON serializable'))

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I am using Celery - Redis - Django rest framework together.
The error happens when I try to pass the serializer to the delay of celery within the Django rest framework.

Here is the viewset

```
class TestSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)

         if serializer.is_valid():

            image_uploaded= "static_path"
            
            json_data = base64.b64encode(np.array(image_uploaded)).decode('ascii')
            result = test_call.delay({'image': json_data})
            result = test_call.delay(serializer)

            data = {"task": result.task_id}

            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@shared_task(name="values")
def test_call(decoded_image):
    return decoded_image
```

The error I get is

> EncodeError(TypeError('Object of type Response is not JSON
> serializable'))

**Update:**
Even when I do this, I still get an error

```
result = test_call.delay({"task": 1})

@shared_task(name="values")
def test_call(decoded_image):
    return {"task": 2}
```

Comment: Where is TestSerializer defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't going to answer your question, but I can't leave a comment (low reputation).

It seems that you are trying to JSON Serialize something that obviously isn't JSON serializable. Based on the name, it is some kind of image data. You could try a different workflow that should be JSON Serializable, example:

One Example:

1. first save the image somewhere that is accessible later and add the location in the serializer (S3 bucket and then a link to the image)
2. In your celery task, fetch the image data based on that location

Second Example:

1. convert the image data into something JSON serializable like a Base64 image string

Comment: as mentioned briefly this helped and I started another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69942867/how-to-serialize-data-from-celery-to-django-rest-framework