# How to serialize data from celery to django rest framework

Tags: python, django, http, redis, celery

I am using Celery - Redis - Django rest framework (DRF).
What I am trying to do:

- DRF Passes URL to the celery task/function
- Celery then fetches that image and applies the logic
- Celery Sends id of new object created
- DRF retrieves the instance from the object saved and serializes and sends it to react (the problem is in this step)

I am not able to unpack and serialize the message from celery so I am able to send it as a response.

Here is my code:

Here is the viewset

```
class TestSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WebsiteURLSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = WebsiteURLSerializer(data=request.data)

         if serializer.is_valid():

            url_site= serializer.validated_data['url']
            result = test_call.delay(url_site)

            result_unpacked = WebsiteURLSerializer(ModelName.objects.filter(pk=result.get()))
            #the below line seems return an empty response
            return Response(result_unpacked.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@shared_task(name="values")
def test_call(url_image):
    model_instance = ModelName.objects.create()
    ..some logic
    model_instance.save()

    return model_instance.id
```

Comment: You need to provide more details, what is exactly the problem ? is there some kind of error that you're facing ? did the image fetching succeed ? Also why are you using celery when your call to the task is synchronous?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was in the following line

From:

```
result_unpacked = WebsiteURLSerializer(ModelName.objects.filter(pk=result.get()))
```

To:

```
result_unpacked = WebsiteURLSerializer(ModelName.objects.get(pk=result.get()))
```